# Retrieving Oauth2 token in swagger and interfacing with API using Python

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests, swagger

I am new to python and I am trying to write a simple program that sends a DNA sequence to an API and returns some simple parameters back. From what I understand this uses Oauth2.0 authentication so I need to request a token using my clientID and client secret and then pass this token through a post request along with the data to recieve the desired output. The API is through swagger and using their interface I can send and recieve the data, but I have no idea how to actually implement this in code. Below is the output generated from the API via swagger:

Curl

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer <XXXXXXXXXXXXX>' -d '{ \ 
   "Sequence": "TGACCCCATATTGGGAGG", \ 
   "NaConc": 50, \ 
   "FoldingTemp": 25, \ 
   "MgConc": 0, \ 
   "NucleotideType": "DNA" \ 
 }' 'https://www.idtdna.com/Restapi/v1/OligoAnalyzer/Hairpin'
```

Response Body

```
[
  {
    "id": "521e5459-236b-4443-9236-f6ade040ac3d",
    "sequence": "CAGCAGTCATGCAATCG",
    "thermo": 49.3,
    "deltaS": -94.91,
    "deltaG": -2.3,
    "deltaH": -30.6,
    "success": true,
    "RNA": false,
    "errorMessages": []
  }
]
```

Request URL

```
https://www.idtdna.com/Restapi/v1/OligoAnalyzer/Hairpin
```

[swagger interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ7vI.png)
[swagger authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihOOv.png)

I tried to implement this in python by sending a post request and passing in the clientID and client secret as the authentication along with a dictionary of the data input.

```
import requests
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

username = 'MyUsername'
password = 'MyPassword'

client_id = 'MyClientID'
client_secret = 'MySecret'

authorize_url = 'https://www.idtdna.com/IdentityServer/connect/authorize'
token_url = 'https://www.idtdna.com/IdentityServer/connect/token'

redirect_uri = 'https://www.idtdna.com/Restapi/swagger/docs/v1'

application_url = 'https://www.idtdna.com/Restapi/v1/OligoAnalyzer/Hairpin'

HairPinRequest = {
    'Sequence': 'CGATCGATCGAT',
    'NaConc': 50,
    'FoldingTemp': 25,
    'MgConc': 0,
    'NucleotideType': 'DNA'
}

oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=application_url)

token = oauth.fetch_token(
    token_url, 
    authorize_url,
    username=username,
    password=password,
    client_id=client_id, 
    client_secret=client_secret 
    )

response = oauth.post(application_url, data=HairPinRequest)

print(response.url)
print(response)
```

Running this code generates an unauthorized client error:

```
\DNAsequencer.py", line 38, in <module> 
    client_secret=client_secret
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth2_session.py", line 360, in fetch_token    
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\clients\base.py", line 421, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 431, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\parameters.py", line 438, in validate_token_parameters
    raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth2\rfc6749\errors.py", line 405, in raise_from_error 
    raise cls(**kwargs)
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.UnauthorizedClientError: (unauthorized_client)
```

So I know that it is reaching the API, but not authenticating properly. Two things I'm still not sure are correct are the `scope` and `redirect_uri`. I'm not exactly sure what addresses to use or how to identify the appropriate ones.

If anyone could help provide some assistance or suggestions on how to properly implement this that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI there is the `requests-oauthlib` library to handle OAuth 2 flows. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/#oauth-2-and-openid-connect-authentication

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this documentation. I have not had success yet but I think I made some progress towards my goal. I edited the post to reflect the updates.

Answer (score 0):

In case the OP or anyone else still finds this useful, here is my solution to the question.  I have an account with the vendor API and am able to get the desired response.
I am still trying to figure out the other tools.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import requests
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

username = 'redacted'
password = 'redacted'
client_id = 'redacted'
client_secret = 'redacted'
authorize_url = 'https://www.idtdna.com/IdentityServer/connect/authorize'
token_url = 'https://www.idtdna.com/IdentityServer/connect/token'
redirect_uri = 'https://www.idtdna.com/Restapi/swagger/docs/v1'
application_url = 'https://www.idtdna.com/Restapi/v1/OligoAnalyzer/Hairpin'
scope = 'test'

HairPinRequest = {
    'Sequence': 'CGATCGATCGAT',
    'NaConc': 50,
    'FoldingTemp': 25,
    'MgConc': 0,
    'NucleotideType': 'DNA'
}

#This token request code does work
payload = "grant_type=password&client_id=redacted&client_secret=redacted&username=redacted&password=redacted&scope=test"

headers = { 'accept': "application/json", 'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
response = requests.request("POST", token_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
#This prints a text version
print(response.text)
#This creates a json object and allows access_token to be used as variable
j = response.json()

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " +j['access_token'] }
```

The response is a json object

> {"access_token":"redacted","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"}
> [{'id': '2a139206-3e86-4eb6-9d77-0a14bdde73b5', 'sequence':
> 'CGATCGATCGAT', 'thermo': 47.1, 'deltaS': -80.88, 'deltaG': -1.79,
> 'deltaH': -25.9, 'success': True, 'RNA': False, 'errorMessages': []}]